# Batch File - Continuing Commands after accessing a networked Computer

Tags: batch-file, cmd, remote-desktop

I need to change gateway address on multiple computers throughout the year and I wanted to create a batch file that would make my life a whole lot easier. The problem I am having is that once the batch file connects another computer, it no longer continues running the batch I coded until I "exit" from their computer and then it runs.

> set /p ComName= Input Computer Name:
>
> cd \diag
>
> psexec \%ComName% cmd.exe
>
> netsh interface ip set address name="local area connection" gateway=192.X.X.XXX gwmetric=0
>
> ipconfig

After it runs the `"psexec \%ComName% cmd.exe"`, what do I need to have that would allow the rest of my batch file run on the other computer?

Comment: Put the commands you want to run on the remote computer into a batch file and then run it on the remote computer using psexec.

Comment: There has to be an alternative to that. I have close to 400 computers. I can't go to each computer, create a batch file and edit it every time I wish to run this batch file from my computer. Is there any possibility of getting my batch file to do everything from my computer?

Comment: The batch file can just exist on your computer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could run each command with `PSEXEC`. You wouldn't need to run `CMD.EXE` remotely.

Comment: The purpose of this experiment was to remove having to type in as many commands as possible. But I think I found an answer to my question with part of your original answer of having a batch file on each computer.

Comment: I created a batch file that does everything I need it to and saved it within the network itself. My batch file on my system asks for the name of the computer, accesses their computer and all I type is \\folder\n.bat (example) and it runs the rest of the batch file and brings me back to my command prompt at which points runs a loop that asks if I want to run it again then asks for a new value for "ComName".

Comment: I was really hoping to just have everything run off my batch file without having to type a single command and just input data but I guess that second one on the network is a necessity.

Comment: You can do what you want...see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple different ways.

### Option 1 - One batch file

```
SET /P ComName=Input Computer Name:
CD \diag

PSEXEC \\%ComName% netsh interface ...<your parameters>...
PSEXEC \\%ComName% ipconfig
```

### Option 2 - Two batch files

**First.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P ComName=Input Computer Name:
CD \diag

PSEXEC \\%ComName% -c Second.cmd
```

Note the `-c` parameter. It tells `PSEXEC` to copy the file to be run to the remote machine first.

**Second.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
netsh interface ...<your parameters>...
ipconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the commands as arguments to `cmd` with the `/C` option and explicitly call `exit`

```
psexec \\%ComName% cmd /C "( netsh interface ip set address name="local area connection" gateway=192.X.X.XXX gwmetric=0 && ipconfig ) & exit"
```